# javascript create element in loop, one by one

Tags: javascript, loops, createelement

I can not find an answer to my problem, being beginner in javascript!

I want to create a new "INPUT" element at the click in a loop, limited to a maximum of 15 elements.

However with my code below, when I click on my button he created me 15 element "INPUT" at once!

I'm trying to create them one by one, up to 15

---

HTML

```
<input class="objetInputSuivant" type="text" id="objetCampement_1" maxlength="18" placeholder="OBJET" onkeyup='this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()'>
<input class="poidsInputSuivant" type="number" id="poidsCampement_1" onkeyup="TotalCalcul(); limit(this);" placeholder="POIDS" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode == 44 || event.charCode == 188 || event.charCode == 190)">

<div id="AddChampCampement"></div>

   <button class="buttonAdd" type="button" width="295px" height="50px" onclick="NewInput()">AJOUTER UN OBJET</button>

   <input class="totalInput" type="number" id="totalCampement" value="0" readonly>
```

---

JAVASCRIPT

```
function NewInput() {

    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

        let Objet = document.createElement("INPUT");
        let Poids = document.createElement("INPUT");

        Objet.type = "text";
        Objet.className = "objetInput";
        Objet.placeholder = "OBJET";
        Objet.onkeyup = function() {
            this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
        }
        Objet.maxLength = 18;

        document.getElementById("AddChampCampement").appendChild(Objet);

        Poids.type = "number";
        Poids.className = "poidsInput";
        Poids.placeholder = "POIDS";
        Poids.id = "poidsCampement_" + i;
        Poids.onkeypress = function() {
            return !(event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode == 44 || event.charCode == 188 || event.charCode == 190);
        }
        Poids.onkeyup = function() {
            limit(this);
        }

        document.getElementById("AddChampCampement").appendChild(Poids);

    }
}
```

Comment: So do not loop....

Comment: the thing if I do not loop, I do not have my id single

Comment: You can store that `i` outside the loop, in a global variable, or better, a closure variable.

Comment: So you store the current index and add one each time....

Comment: if you can show me that I would be delighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

great for the limitation, so I took your two answers, and it works to keep the unique ID with the limitation.

here is the code:

```
const NewInput = (function() {
    let i = 0;

    return function NewInput() {
        i++;
        if(document.getElementById("AddChampCampement").childNodes.length<30){
        let Objet = document.createElement("INPUT");
        let Poids = document.createElement("INPUT");

        Objet.type = "text";
        Objet.className = "objetInput";
        Objet.placeholder = "OBJET";
        Objet.onkeyup = function() {
            this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
        }
        Objet.maxLength = 18;

        document.getElementById("AddChampCampement").appendChild(Objet);

        Poids.type = "number";
        Poids.className = "poidsInput";
        Poids.placeholder = "POIDS";
        Poids.id = "poidsCampement_" + i;
        Poids.onkeypress = function() {
            return !(event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode == 44 || event.charCode == 188 || event.charCode == 190);
        }
        Poids.onkeyup = function() {
            limit(this);
        }

        document.getElementById("AddChampCampement").appendChild(Poids);

    }}

})()
```

Answer (score 0):

This version stores the current value of `i` in a closure.  You could also do this with a global variable (not recommended), in the browser's localStorage (unlikely, but possible), or in a hidden spot in the DOM, and probably in other places as well.

Note the [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) which stores `i` and returns the function which has `i` in scope.

```js
const NewInput = (function() {
  let i = 0;

  return function NewInput() {
    i++; // TODO: escape early if `i` is larger than 15
    let Objet = document.createElement("INPUT");
    let Poids = document.createElement("INPUT");

    Objet.type = "text";
    Objet.className = "objetInput";
    Objet.placeholder = "OBJET";
    Objet.onkeyup = function() {
      this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    }
    Objet.maxLength = 18;

    document.getElementById("AddChampCampement").appendChild(Objet);

    Poids.type = "number";
    Poids.className = "poidsInput";
    Poids.placeholder = "POIDS";
    Poids.id = "poidsCampement_" + i;
    Poids.onkeypress = function() {
      return !(event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode == 44 || event.charCode == 188 || event.charCode == 190);
    }
    Poids.onkeyup = function() {
      limit(this);
    }

    document.getElementById("AddChampCampement").appendChild(Poids);
  }

})()

const limit = function() {console.log('limit not implemented yet');}
```

```html
<input class="objetInputSuivant" type="text" id="objetCampement_1" maxlength="18" placeholder="OBJET" onkeyup='this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()'>
<input class="poidsInputSuivant" type="number" id="poidsCampement_1" onkeyup="TotalCalcul(); limit(this);" placeholder="POIDS" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode == 44 || event.charCode == 188 || event.charCode == 190)">

<div id="AddChampCampement"></div>

   <button class="buttonAdd" type="button" width="295px" height="50px" onclick="NewInput()">AJOUTER UN OBJET</button>

   <input class="totalInput" type="number" id="totalCampement" value="0" readonly>
```

Comment: I just tested your answer, it's a success!
I'm starting to understand better and better the logic
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should make the function run 15 times max, but you add two input fields at a time in the code so I set the max elements to 30. The ids will start from 1 and increments by 2 each time. I'm using the number of children in the in "AddChampCampement" since it updates without setting any global values :)

```
function NewInput() {
  if(document.getElementById("AddChampCampement").childNodes.length<30){
    console.log(document.getElementById("AddChampCampement").childNodes.length)
    let Objet = document.createElement("INPUT");
    let Poids = document.createElement("INPUT");
    Objet.type = "text";
    Objet.className = "objetInput";
    Objet.placeholder = "OBJET";
    Objet.onkeyup = function() {
      this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    }
    Objet.maxLength = 18;

    document.getElementById("AddChampCampement").appendChild(Objet);

    Poids.type = "number";
    Poids.className = "poidsInput";
    Poids.placeholder = "POIDS";
    Poids.id = "poidsCampement_" + document.getElementById("AddChampCampement").childNodes.length;
    Poids.onkeypress = function() {
      return !(event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode == 44 || event.charCode == 188 || event.charCode == 190);
    }
    Poids.onkeyup = function() {
      limit(this);
    }
    document.getElementById("AddChampCampement").appendChild(Poids);
  }
}
```